# Spring Security secure custom pages

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is there a way to configure Spring Security (with Java config) in order to secure custom pages only, or even work upon `@PreAuthorized` annotation?

The idea is that I want to secure custom calls like `/admin` and other stuff (without hardcoding every call in the security configuration), which is set up in the controller under the mentioned annotation, but the other stuff shouldn't use authentication at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a hard time finding something which would work for me. That does the trick and it's also very readable.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
}
```

and the **full Class** for those who are still not on the same page

```java
package com.your.package.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Note that not calling the `formLogin()` method would make the default "/login" return a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answers your question, but you could use ant matchers to identify certain pages and ignore others in your security configuration, like so:

```
.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
```

or

```
.antMatcher("/admin/**")
.authorizeRequests()
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633194/spring-security-configuration-for-basic-authentication-and-form-login/35634692#35634692 here you can find two working examples, maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The second vers came out to be what i needed, but still, this is more of a hardcode ("/admin/**").

But the ending result came out to be from the "other side" of the system - i simply added 
     @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')")
for the Controller definition, which helped me to derive the main calls from the ones i need extra security on.

Comment: If you want to completely remove hard-coded values in your java configuration classes, you could define an abstract class with constants, like ADMIN_PATH = "/admin/" and use it both in your controller and security config, or even better define it in a properties file.

Comment: Begining to hate Spring Security. After a few restarts of the project the predefined ROLE_ANONUMOUS stoped working, and i havent got a clue WHY.

The "/" started to go redirect:/login even with the @PreAuthorized annotation in the controller.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, I'm no expert myself :-), what I would do is test things one by one by adding or removing config details, until I understand exactly what does and doesn't work, do things in baby steps :-)

Comment: The thing is cant get a decent configuration, that would work under "see permission - isnt permitted -> redirect to login page"